# How did Apple implement the BookMark feature on its iOS Books app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, pdfkit

I am making a PDF Reader similar to the Books App built in on iOS. My bookmarks work and update, except when I exit the PDF View and go back to document browsing (file picker), then open my PDF again. Then my app crashes:

```
    private func updateBookmarkStatus() {

        if let documentURL = pdfDocument?.documentURL?.absoluteString,
            let bookmarks = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: documentURL) as? [Int],
            let currentPage = pdfView.currentPage,
            let index = pdfDocument?.index(for: currentPage) {
      /*crashes on this line*/:  bookmarkButton.image = bookmarks.contains(index) ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-P") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-N")
        } else {
            print("Bookmark Error")
        }
    }
```

with

```
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:
```

The line that I put the comment on just updates the bookmark to the "filled version", showing the user that the page is bookmarked.

The bookmark updates and works within the PDF. It is once I go out of the PDF, to the document browsing, then go back into the PDF that it crashes. It might be worth noting that "Bookmark Error" gets printed when I initially open the PDF for the first time.

If I do not touch the bookmark button, then I can go to document browsing and reopen the PDF as many times as I want. But as soon as I touch the bookmark button, I cannot re-open my PDF file again.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try putting `bookmarks.contains(index)` into the `if let ... ` line?

Comment: @koen I get the same error. I put a comma after the last statement in the if let ... and I put bookmarks.contains(index).

Comment: So did you write is as `... if let contains =  bookmarks.contains(index) { bookmarkButton.image = contains ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-P") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-N")`? Are you sure that Bookmark-P and Bookmark-N are not nil?

Comment: "It might be worth noting that "Bookmark Error" gets printed when I initially open the PDF for the first time." Did you expect this?

Comment: @koen they are not nil. Also, how can I write it as such? I can't insert another "if" statement into that sequence.

Comment: Remove the `if` I accidentally included. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It says, "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'"